# Using a template engine to restructure JSON?

Tags: node.js

Is it a bad practice to use a template engine to restructure a JSON object? Of course i can do it manually but i want to avoid the `null` check route if possible.

Update: Can those who downvoted at least explain why?

Comment: You want something similar to XSLT but for JSON, right?

Comment: @Ben yes but i couldn't get `node_xslt` to install? Both on node and iojs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For something like XPath for JSON, use JSONPath:

- http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/
- https://github.com/s3u/JSONPath

JSONPath produces an array of items matching the selection. You can combine that with JavaScript array `forEach` method to do most of what is typically done in XSLT templates.

Alternatively, you can use jsonpath-object-transform which provides a little bit more in the way of templates:

- https://github.com/dvdln/jsonpath-object-transform#readme